# InputLabel of Material UI not aligning properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

### The material UI InputLabel is not aligning as intended

I wanted to add the password field for authentication while Signing up but the label of the password field is not aligned properly as shown in the image

```
<div className="register">
      <h2>
        <OfflineBoltRoundedIcon
          sx={{ fontSize: '3.5rem', position: 'relative', top: '1rem' }}
        />
        Electrify
      </h2>
      <h1>Sign up with your email address</h1>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: '20rem' }} variant="outlined">
        <p>What's your email?</p>
        <TextField
          id="email"
          label="Email"
          variant="outlined"
          color="secondary"
          name="email"
          fullWidth
        />
        <p>Create a password</p>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-password" color="secondary">
          Password
        </InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput
          id="outlined-adornment-password"
          type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
          value={values.password}
          onChange={handleChange('password')}
          endAdornment={
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <IconButton
                aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                edge="end"
              >
                {values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          }
          label="Password"
          color="secondary"
          aria-describedby="outlined-password-helper-text"
        />

        <FormHelperText id="outlined-password-helper-text">
          Enter a 6 digit password
        </FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
```

[The password label is not aligned properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrtLd.png)

Comment: I think you need to wrap `InputLabel` and `OutlinedInput` in a `FormControl` for it to align properly. Alternatively, you can also add adornments in the standard `TextField`.

Comment: Oh thanks I missed the FormControl wrapping but it messes up the whole design like they come in a single line, but that of using adornments in TextField how can we use it that prop isn't specified in the docs

Comment: You can pass an object in the `InputProps` prop of `TextField`, with `endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">...</InputAdornment>` as a key-value pair. [Check the 2nd example here](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#icons)

Comment: Thank you @kausko that solved my problem by converting that password Input to TextField, but they should also update the code in the docs about the password input one ... is it open source so that I can open an issue?

Comment: All examples are available [here](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#InputWithIcon.js) and [here](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#InputAdornments.js). It's open source, but definitely take a look at these links before raising an issue.

Comment: yes yes in the other component examples of the InputProps they are used with textfield idk why did they use that password example without it...